# I need to get a value between two limits using a do/while loop. The code breaks when I put two conditions in while()

Tags: c, cs50

So in need to get a value between 1 and 8 (both inclusive). So I wrote a simple do/while loop in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
   int height;
   do
   {
      height = get_int("Height: ");
   }while (height > 9);
}
```

Now this works and repeats until the value is below 9. But as soon I change the condition for the while from

```
while (height > 9);
```

to

```
while (height > 9 && height <0);
```

it starts to accept numbers higher than 9. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: How can a number be **greater than 9** and **less than 0** at the same time? think about it.

Comment: oh yeah, right!! I need to use "or" instead  of "and"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `while (height > 9 && height < 0` to `while (height > 9 || height < 0)` should do the trick. Ponder over it.